# C segfault when modifiy array value

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, undefined-behavior, string-literals

Im getting a segfault when changing dna[i] to U, Ive debbuged but I still cant understand why.

Also I was comparing the value at a position against T with strcmp, but from what I understand thats for string literals and I can simply compare it with `dna[i] == 'T'`. Is that right? thanks.

```
#include <string.h>

char *dna_to_rna(char *dna) {
    int size = (int)( sizeof(dna) / sizeof(dna[0]));
    char *retour[size];
    strcpy(retour, dna);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (dna[i] == 'T') {
            dna[i] = 'U';
        }
    }
    return (char *) retour;
}

int main() {
    char *dna[] = {
            "TTTT",
            "GCAT",
            "GACCGCCGCC"
    };

    char *actual, *expected;
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n < 3; ++n) {
        actual = dna_to_rna(*(dna + n));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String literals cannot be modified and your `dna` array is full of pointers to string literals

Comment: I also don't understand the purpose of the modifying `dna` instead of `retour` in your function

Comment: in `dna_to_rna()` function,  `sizeof(dna)` does not return the size of the array passed as argument: it simply returns the size of a pointer to char. The number of char in a string is obtained with `strlen()`.

Comment: Side note: instead of the ugly `*(dna + n)` you should use the more commun form `dna[n]`. It's exactly the same thing, but latter is more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to the function `dna_to_rna` a pointer to a string literal

```
actual = dna_to_rna(*(dna + n));
```

and then within the function you are trying to change the string literal

```
    if (dna[i] == 'T') {
        dna[i] = 'U';
    }
```

Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Also the expression with the `sizeof` operator in this declaration

```
int size = (int)( sizeof(dna) / sizeof(dna[0]));
```

does not make a sense. It evaluates the size of a pointer of the type `char *`.

Instead you should use the standard string function `strlen`.

And this declaration is incorrect

```
char *retour[size];
```

At least you need a character array instead of an array of pointers.

```
 char retour[size];
```

And the function returns a pointer to an array with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function

```
char *dna_to_rna(char *dna) {
    //...
    char retour[size];
    //...
    return (char *) retour;
}
```

that is the function returns an invalid pointer.

You should dynamically allocate a character array within the function with the length `strlen( dna ) + 1` and change and return this array.

It seems what you mean is something like the following

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * dna_to_rna( const char *dna ) 
{
    size_t n = strlen( dna );
    char *retour = malloc( n + 1 );

    if ( retour != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( retour, dna );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
        {
           if ( retour[i] == 'T' ) retour[i] = 'U';
        }
    }

    return retour;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Ill study the modifications you did.

Comment: @LIsa I hope it will be useful.:)